# Scroll event on fullscreen mode

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, fullscreen, html5-fullscreen

I have to register the vertical scroll, so I use this code.

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {

    console.log("scrollVertical:"+window.scrollY);
});
```

It works fine. But then I need to enter fullscreen mode so I do this.

```
(...)
document.getElementById('myDiv').requestFullscreen();
(...)
```

When in fullscreen mode, it doesn't work. Anyone has any ideas as to why?

Comment: Hi. Can you please give us more information about the browsers that you are testing and perhaps a full working example? Thank you

Comment: Sorry about that. Fixing it right away.

Comment: Turns out my question is not that simple. I tried to only show relevant code, but I have to try some new things I bumped into before editing. Thanks anyways.